# Differences between SVR with a linear kernel and linear least squares

Tags: regression, svm

I've been working on a toy problem of predicting reviews a product will get in the future. I found that SVR with a linear kernel worked better than doing a linear least squares regression on the data (even though both were pretty terrible), but I had no intuition about which one works better and why. What are some examples of using one versus the other? Can both usually be used?